# How Do I define a microk8s.ctr filter?

Tags: microk8s, containerd

The output for microk8s.ctr image ls --help gives:

```
NAME:
   ctr images list - list images known to containerd

USAGE:
   ctr images list [command options] [flags] [<filter>, ...]

DESCRIPTION:
   list images registered with containerd

OPTIONS:
   --quiet, -q  print only the image refs
```

I can't find a doc anywhere that describes how to define the filter. How does one do this? For instance, where the ref includes "kafa" in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a filter using quotes and an operator `("=="|"!="|"~=")` for example:

```
microk8s ctr i ls "name~=kafa"
```

Comment: This does not work.  If I do: `microk8s ctr images ls | grep kafka`, I get a number of  entries, where kafka is in the REF column: `docker.io/bitnami/kafka:2.7.0-debian-10-r1`.  If I do `microk8s ctr images ls "ref~=kafka"`, I get nothing, except the header.  I get the same result if I try to filter on platforms or type, even with exact match. `  microk8s ctr images ls "platforms==linux/amd64"`  yields only `REF TYPE DIGEST SIZE PLATFORMS LABELS`